# Fastest way to move records from an Oracle database into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle

Ok this is the scenario... I have a table in Oracle that acts like a queue...
A VB.net program reads the queue and calls a stored proc in SQL Server that processes and then inserts the message  into another SQL Server table and then deletes the record from the oracle table.

We use a DataReader to read the records from Oracle and then call the stored proc for each of the records. The program seems to be a little slow. The stored procedure itself isn't slow. The SP by itself when called in a loop can process about 2000 records in 20 seconds. But when called from the .Net program, the execution time is about 5 records per second.
I have seen that most of the time consumed is in calling the stored procedure and waiting for it to return.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is a snippet of the actual code

```
 Function StartDataXfer() As Boolean
  Dim status As Boolean = False
  Try

   SqlConn.Open()
   OraConn.Open()
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Going to Get the messages from oracle", 1)

   If GetMsgsFromOracle() Then
    c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Got messages from oracle", 1)

    If ProcessMessages() Then
     c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Finished Processing all messages in the queue", 0)
     status = True
    Else
     c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Failed to Process all messages in the queue", 0)
     status = False
    End If
   Else
    status = True
   End If
   StartDataXfer = status
  Catch ex As Exception
  Finally
   SqlConn.Close()
   OraConn.Close()
  End Try
 End Function
 Private Function GetMsgsFromOracle() As Boolean
  Try
   OraDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
   OraDataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
   OraSelCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
   GetMsgsFromOracle = False
   With OraSelCmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .Connection = OraConn
    .CommandText = GetMsgSql
   End With
   OraDataAdapter.SelectCommand = OraSelCmd
   OraDataAdapter.Fill(OraDataTable)
   If OraDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    GetMsgsFromOracle = True
   End If
  Catch ex As Exception
   GetMsgsFromOracle = False
  End Try
 End Function

 Private Function ProcessMessages() As Boolean
  Try
   ProcessMessages = False
   PrepareSQLInsert()
   PrepOraDel()

   i = 0
   Dim Method As Integer
   Dim OraDataRow As DataRow
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Going to call message sending procedure", 2)
   For Each OraDataRow In OraDataTable.Rows
    With OraDataRow
     Method = GetMethod(.Item(0))
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("RelLifeTime").Value = c.RelLifetime
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("Param1").Value = Nothing
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("ID").Value = GenerateTransactionID()  ' Nothing
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("UID").Value = Nothing
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("Param").Value = Nothing
     SQLInsCmd.Parameters("Credit").Value = 0
     SQLInsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

     'check the return value
     If SQLInsCmd.Parameters("ReturnValue").Value = 1 And SQLInsCmd.Parameters("OutPutParam").Value = 0 Then   'success
      'delete the input record from the source table once it is logged
      c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Moved record successfully", 2)
      OraDataAdapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters("P(0)").Value = OraDataRow.Item(6)
      OraDataAdapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Deleted record successfully", 2)
      OraDataAdapter.Update(OraDataTable)
      c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Committed record successfully", 2)
      i = i + 1
     Else   'failure 
      c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Failed to exec: " & c.DestIns & "Status: " & SQLInsCmd.Parameters("OutPutParam").Value & " and TrackId: " & SQLInsCmd.Parameters("TrackID").Value.ToString, 0)
     End If
     If File.Exists("stop.txt") Then
      c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Stop File Found", 1)
      'ProcessMessages = True
      'Exit Function
      Exit For
     End If
    End With
   Next
   OraDataAdapter.Update(OraDataTable)
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Updated Oracle Table", 1)
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--Moved " & i & " records from Oracle to SQL Table", 1)
   ProcessMessages = True
  Catch ex As Exception
   ProcessMessages = False
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--MoveMsgsToSQL: " & ex.Message, 0)
  Finally
   OraDataTable.Clear()
   OraDataTable.Dispose()
   OraDataAdapter.Dispose()
   OraDelCmd.Dispose()
   OraDelCmd = Nothing
   OraSelCmd = Nothing
   OraDataTable = Nothing
   OraDataAdapter = Nothing
  End Try

 End Function


 Public Function GenerateTransactionID() As Int64
  Dim SeqNo As Int64
  Dim qry As String
  Dim SqlTransCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
  qry = " select seqno from StoreSeqNo"
  SqlTransCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  SqlTransCmd.Connection = SqlConn
  SqlTransCmd.CommandText = qry
  SeqNo = SqlTransCmd.ExecuteScalar

  If SeqNo > 2147483647 Then
   qry = "update StoreSeqNo set seqno=1"
   SqlTransCmd.CommandText = qry
   SqlTransCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   GenerateTransactionID = 1
  Else
   qry = "update StoreSeqNo set seqno=" & SeqNo + 1
   SqlTransCmd.CommandText = qry
   SqlTransCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   GenerateTransactionID = SeqNo
  End If

 End Function
 Private Function PrepareSQLInsert() As Boolean
  'function to prepare the insert statement for the insert into the SQL stmt using 
  'the sql procedure SMSProcessAndDispatch
  Try
   Dim dr As DataRow
   SQLInsCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
   With SQLInsCmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .Connection = SqlConn
    .CommandText = SQLInsProc

    .Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer)
    .Parameters("ReturnValue").Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    .Parameters.Add("OutPutParam", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer)
    .Parameters("OutPutParam").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    .Parameters.Add("TrackID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 70)
    .Parameters.Add("RelLifeTime", OleDb.OleDbType.TinyInt)
    .Parameters("RelLifeTime").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Parameters.Add("Param1", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 160)
    .Parameters("Param1").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Parameters.Add("TransID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 70)
    .Parameters("TransID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Parameters.Add("UID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 20)
    .Parameters("UID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Parameters.Add("Param", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 160)
    .Parameters("Param").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Parameters.Add("CheckCredit", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer)
    .Parameters("CheckCredit").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Prepare()
   End With
  Catch ex As Exception
   c.ErrorLog(Now.ToString & "--PrepareSQLInsert: " & ex.Message)
  End Try
 End Function

 Private Function PrepOraDel() As Boolean
  OraDelCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
  Try
   PrepOraDel = False
   With OraDelCmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .Connection = OraConn
    .CommandText = DelSrcSQL
    .Parameters.Add("P(0)", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 160)   'RowID
    .Parameters("P(0)").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .Prepare()
   End With
   OraDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = OraDelCmd
   PrepOraDel = True

  Catch ex As Exception
   PrepOraDel = False
  End Try
 End Function
```

WHat i would like to know is, if there is anyway to speed up this program?
Any ideas/suggestions would be highly appreciated...

Regardss,
Chetan

Comment: that looks truly horrible!  ;)

Comment: A wall of code is less likely to get attention than a minimal program that shows the latency problem. The bug might even jump out at you as you go through this process.

Comment: why not create a trigger on the Oracle table to call a script that's capable of calling the SQL SP?

Comment: @Mitch: I agree with you too :)
@Marcelo: Will do that...just didnt want to miss any part of the code that might help in figuring out why its slow..
@Rashad: Dont know much about SSIS, but will give it a try and update here about how it goes...
Thanks all you guys for taking the time to look at this

Comment: @Rashad...sorry that comment was for Mitch...Havent ever tried calling a script from a trigger...will look into that...btw do you have any reference links that could get me started..

Comment: @Chetan: two of my favorite programming aphorisms are "You can’t improve what you haven’t measured" and "Programs spend surprising amounts of time in the damnedest places".  I don't know exactly what you'll find but I wouldn't be surprised if once you can measure just exactly where your app is really spending its time it'll turn out to be someplace you never would have expected it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oracle and SQL Server can participate in a distributed transaction, why not write a SSIS job to query Oracle and run the SQL Server Stored procedure, delete the 'queued' record etc ?

Create a SQL Server linked server to the Oracle database...

[To add to @Bob Jarvis comments about first profiling to make sure the bottleneck is where you think it is: the [EqaTec](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) .NET code profiler is free for personal use...]

Comment: HI guys,

sorry for the delay in updating this...
We tried out most of the suggested possible scenarios and there was a significant increase in the performance as well.
The Code Profiler confirmed what we had suspected that calling the SQl stored proc for each record was taking up most of the time.
So, we have now implemented the current scenario.  We are now using the application to just move the records from Oracle to sql with very little processing and then using a SQL Server Stored Proc to process these records and insert them into another table.

Comment: Initially we were able to process about 3 records per second using the above code.  Now the system processes about 26-30 records per second on the production machine.  The same test on a local test machine yielded about 150-200 records per second. Though this could be bcos the prod. server is very heavily loaded.

Thanks for all your help guys..I guess the next step would be to try and optimize the SQL server itself and see how much more gain we could get from that...BTW...I am marking both the answers as correct because they both helped.. Cheers

Comment: @Chetan: if you are seeing such a big difference in production, I would suggest benchmarking your hardware. Does it have enough RAM? are file/drive placements correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the stored procedure isn't the problem then it must be something associated with calling the stored procedure.  Since we can't change/fix .Net itself, let's look at the things we can change.

When calling the stored procedure you're doing a select and an update of your StoreSeqNo table (see the call to GenerateTransactionID).  This may be part of the slowdown, especially since you're doing a query of StoreSeqNo without a WHERE clause.  In addition I suggest you learn about sequences, which are objects intended to generate non-repeating sequential numbers and are safe to use across transactions, users, etc.  I don't know if SQL Server supports them (haven't used SQL Server for some years now) but I'm sure that they are supported in Oracle.

Also, there's that "Method = GetMethod(.Item(0))" call.  Is GetMethod one of your procedures?  It's not shown in the snippet, but perhaps that's adding some overhead?  You might want to try adding some code to figure out just which lines are taking the most time.  I suspect there's a profiler out there for .Net.

Just some thoughts.  Good luck.

Comment: The sequences is something i will definitely look into...GetMethod is indeed one of the functions , just a simple one that uses Select...cases to return a value...also will put up a profiler...maybe those results would help too... thanks for taking some time to go through this...will keep you posted..

Comment: +1. Good point about profiling if poster sticks with their current method of performing this task.